# How to remove a line bashrc linux

Tags: linux, bash, vim, terminal

Hi as the question says basically, im adding some alias's to my `bashrc` in linux and its keeps messing up and when i try and go up with the cursor its just types `AAA BBBB` etc i know '`o`' adds a new line but what's remove a line?

Comment: You need to read a `vi` manual. To make it easier, type `echo your_alias >> .bashrc` : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are using Vim if you say <kbd>o</kbd> adds a new line. First press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to switch to `normal` mode, then use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to delete a line.

Comment: Cheers, was just about to ask a question but you just answered it in your edit, how about to move the cursor up a line?

Comment: k to move up, j to move down, l to move right, h to move left.  See what @fedorqui posted for more info.

Comment: thank you!! dont know whos answer to accept :( both answered what i asked, flip a coin time i think

Comment: @MarcosSavoury was faster, I would give it to him as he is also newer in the site : )

Comment: Fair enough good man, cheers for the extra info though @MarcosSavoury

Answer (score 7):

vi can be horrible the first times (like beer). But after some time it can be your friend (beer again).

Basic commands:

- `i` start writing
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> back to commands
- `dd` delete a line
- `o` start writing after current line
- `:wq` from *commands* saves and quits from file
- `j`/`k` move cursor down and up (respectively)
- `h`/`l` move cursor left and right (respectively)

Here you have all the possible commands:

> [image: vi commands for each character]

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn some basic `vim`! Type `vimtutor` into your terminal and in ~20 minutes you'll be able to handle 99% of common `vim` commands.

Comment: oh nice one cheers didnt realize there was an in build command for a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Vim unless you're ready to commit to The Journey! (But thank me later if you do!)

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```